# Codeigniter 3 Session not working With PHP 7.1.4

Tags: php, session, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-hmvc, php-7.1

I have an application built with `Codeigniter 3 HMVC`.The application was working fine on PHP `5.6` version, But after upgrading my PHP version to `7.1.4` I was not able to log in into my application. After a complete checkup I found that session is not setting at all.

I role back to PHP `5.6` and session was working fine again while switching to PHP `7.1.4`  bring the "session not working" issue back.

I tried altering some config value like cookie prefix and cookie save name etc, nothing seems to fix it.

Can anyone please help.

Comment: Please, read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [provide an MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). **This is necessary to reproduce your issue** and this is the most useful way for you to learn how to find and fix the problem yourself.

Comment: The question is not about my personal code... it's about a open source framework. Do you want me to paste the whole code of codeigniter 3 here. Anyone who knows codeigniter already have the code.

Comment: It's not a basic level issue like I forgot to auto-load or manually load the session library, this is probably a bug in CI 3.

Comment: How do you know it's not in the application code the source of the problem?

Comment: I mean: there are changes in php7 that involves the session system management in CI3?

Comment: Because : >> sudo a2dismod php5.6 >> sudo a2enmod php7.1 >> sudo service apache2 restart  makes the session not working where >> sudo a2dismod php7.1 >> sudo a2enmod php5.6 >> sudo service apache2 restart makes the session working fine without changing a single character. Hope you got it.

Comment: So in a fresh install of CI3 with php7.1 happens the same problem?

Comment: yes @gp_sflover it might happen as CI3 was for PHP 5.6 + but PHP 7 has a lot of change in functions ... and I'm also focused on find that answer. What should be the change in session library.

Comment: That's the point "_it might happen_". You should test this yourself and then, when you are sure it not depends by your app, come here with a question (_and more useful info_). Even though I think it's better to ask directly to the project maintainer.

Comment: I got my sessions working again by rolling PHP back to 7.0

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found that the issue is with some earlier version of Codeigniter 3 and this is a bug already reported in their website.The underlying session bug has been fixed on:

- 3.1.2
- 3.1.3
- 3.1.4

So in the latest version of Codeigniter 3 this issue doesn't happen.

#### Solutions:

If you are already in a faulty version codeigniter consider replacing system folder with **latest** version's one. Version 3.1.6 at the time writing this.

Comment: I have the same problem with CI 3.1.9 and PHp 7.2.34

Answer (score 0):

In codeigniter 3.1.9 and PHP 7.2 on XAMPP(windows), I checked my application/config/config.php and saw the sess_driver was database:

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = '165_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = "ci_sessions";
```

So I created the database ci_sessions with:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ci_sessions` (
        `id` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
        `ip_address` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
        `timestamp` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
        `data` blob NOT NULL,
        KEY `ci_sessions_timestamp` (`timestamp`)
);
```

And it worked.