# PHP SESSID gets reset on every page load

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-app-engine

My session gets reset very page load, resulting in a login page that doesn't work etc.

Using Google App Engine with PHP 7.2, Codeigniter Framework 3.
Sessions get saved in database.

In Chrome developer tools at Application -> Cookies, the PHPSESSID cookie value changes at every page load. Domain is set to the correct subdomain. Expire date is 1969.

Comment: You should provide the code you are using to set the cookie. It would seem like your expiration is not correct.

Comment: @BA_Webimax Just using standard Codeigniter 3 session library

Comment: check value of PHPSESSID in php `$_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']` and see if it has the value, and look for `session_regenerate_id` in your code maybe you use it somewhere

Comment: I did var_dump($_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']) but it's empty

Comment: @user1857116 It will be very difficult to help you if you don't provide any code. What's in `application/config/config.php` related to sessions and cookies? Are you autoloading the sessions library in `application/config/autoload.php`? How are you initializing the sessions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the issue wasn't with Google App Engine or my settings.
It was a CodeIgniter bug.

If you encounter this too, make sure to upgrade your /system folder to the lastest CodeIgniter 3 version.

source: [Codeigniter 3 Session not working With PHP 7.1.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43718961/codeigniter-3-session-not-working-with-php-7-1-4)