# My CI session destroyed after redirection

Tags: php, session, codeigniter-3

I am using CI 3.1.9. At start everything was working fine but now my CI session gets destroyed automatically but this behavior is random. Sometimes it works fine but most of the time when i login it redirects me to the login page again due to session gets destroyed. I have searched it over stackoverflow.com the found a solution here [Codeigniter session data lost after redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14472869/codeigniter-session-data-lost-after-redirect/50792059#50792059). The solution worked perfect for me but I don't understand what difference does it make by replacing 
    `ini_set('session.name', $params['cookie_name']);` by
    `ini_set('session.id', $params['cookie_name']);`

I have found many solution here [Codeigniter session data lost after redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14472869/codeigniter-session-data-lost-after-redirect/34338027) and solved my issue too but i wanted to know that difference of    `session.id` instead of    `session.name`.
in session library.

Comment: Which CodeIgniter-3 version are you using? in the latest version of Codeigniter 3 this issue doesn't happen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Codeigniter 3 Session not working With PHP 7.1.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43718961/codeigniter-3-session-not-working-with-php-7-1-4)

Comment: @Hkachhia I am using CI 3.1.9. It is not a duplicate question because i am asking here the reason how it solved my problem but just replacing **session.name** with **session.id**. I want to know the what is difference of using these two.